# uninstall magento 2 from web server

Tags: magento2, uninstall

I have just installed magento but I realise the installation was done on the wrong server (mistake from my client). So I need to clear out the entire installation from the current place.

I have tried this from SSH:

php bin/magento setup:uninstall

But it does not work.

And Is it right to delete all the magento files from the installation folder manually and also drop database?

I would be pleased to get help uninstalling this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out..

Had to cd to public_html first

And then run the command:

php bin/magento setup:uninstall

It didnt just uninstall but also dropped all tables earlier created in the magento database... :)